# Dialogo invertido na integração do watson com o telegram

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, watson

Ao iniciar a conversa com o Watson as mensagens aparecem invertidas, primeiro ele deveria dizer:

> Olá, Alexandre, eu sou o Jairo!

para só após dizer:

> Estou aqui para lembrar você [...]

Essa integração foi feita utilizando o NodeJS.

Código:

```
[...]
telegramBot.on('message', function (msg) {
    // msg = mensagem do usuário

    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    context.nome = msg.from.first_name; 

    conversation.message({
            workspace_id: env.workspace_id,
            input: {'text': msg.text},
            context: context
        },  function(err, response) {
            if (err)
                console.log('error:', err);
            else{

                context = response.context;
                context.nome = msg.from.first_name;

                if(response.output.text.length > 0){
                    response.output.text.forEach(resposta => {
                        //resposta = resposta do watson
                        telegramBot.sendMessage(chatId, resposta);  
                    });
                }else{
                    let resposta = response.output.text[0];
                    telegramBot.sendMessage(chatId, resposta);  
                }
            }
        }); 
    });

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Provavelmente o valor do input está chegando primeiro que a requisição de um anova conversa.
Tenta iniciar passar um valor "None" no campo de mensagem ou não evocar a mensagem, para só depois enviar a requisição.
Exemplo:
1° Chama a API sem mensagem
2° Passa o valor da mensagem

Comment: Oi, podes dar um exemplo de código?

Answer (score -1):

Na linha abaixo deveria ser:

if(response.output.text.length > 1){

Pois ai você vai enviar para o telegram todas as respostas com seu for, correto. Do jeito que está, vindo 1 única resposta ele entrará nesta lógica. De qualquer maneira não corrige a ordem das respostas, mas me parece um erro de lógica.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).